# jQuery if statement using URL that needs to do select all pages in section with exceptions

Tags: jquery, if-statement

The specific problem is that I have a button that needs to show up in a specific section of the site. However, there are a few pages within that section that I do NOT want it to show up on. So the button should be hidden on most pages of the site, showing in one section ("foo"), and hidden on a page within that section ("foo/hey").

The problem is that once it passes the first if statement the second is ignored.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
$(function () {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("foo") > -1) {
    console.log('button should show here');
  } 
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("foo/hey") > -1) {
    console.log('button should get hidden here');
  } 
  else {
    console.log('button should get hidden on any other page of the site');
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought I said it above but perhaps I wasn't clear enough. 

The specific problem is that I have a button that needs to show up in a specific section of the site. However, there are a few pages within that section that I do NOT want it to show up on. 

So the button should be hidden on most pages of the site, showing in one section ("foo"), and hidden on a page within that section ("foo/hey"). 

Does that make sense?

Comment: you should do this with includes and other more idiomatic ways of building the markup in the actual pages or on the server side not with checking the url, this is about the most backwards way of solving the problem. `X/Y Problem` and off-topic otherwise Too Broad/Opinion Based to explain more correct solutions.

Comment: Your `else` is only attached to the second `if`. So it will be executed even if the first `if` is executed.

Comment: I only have access to the header template on this project at the moment so I have to work with what I have. Moving the second `if` after the `else` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showHideButtonsWinLoc();
  $('#windowLoc').on('input', function() {
    showHideButtonsWinLoc();
  });
});

function showHideButtonsWinLoc() {
    var windowLoc = window.location.href;
    
    //Remove, testing only
    var inVal = $('#windowLoc').val();
    if(inVal.length > 0) {
        windowLoc = inVal;
    }
    
    
    if (windowLoc.indexOf("foo/hey") > -1) {
      $('#importantBtn').hide();
    } else if (windowLoc.indexOf("foo") > -1) {
      $('#importantBtn').show();
    } else {
      $('#importantBtn').hide();
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      URL to Test: <input id="windowLoc" placeholder="Window Location">
    </div>
    <button id="importantBtn">Important Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what's wrong in the original code and how the solution fixes it, not just dump a bunch of code.

Comment: Ok Barmar, feel free to leave one of those "good answers" There's a textbox that says: "Add Answer" at the bottom of the page that you can use

Comment: The code in my answer would be essentially the same as yours, it seems redundant. I'd like to help you improve your answer rather than waste time writing a new one.